# Asp.NET MVC 5 display image from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to display an picture from my database.
First I made a Model called `ShopModels.cs` inside that models i have this(which i think is good for now):

```
    public class ShopModels
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And after I made that model I have scaffolded my controllers and views
In my controller I did not change anything for the images only for other things.
And for my View(view folder called: ShopModels) what is called Detials.cshtml

And inside my Detials.cshtml I have changed this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Photo)
```

to this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(@Model.Photo)" />
```

It still does not work and it also does not give me an error.

---

My db looks like this:
I have tryed tried to change

> Photos/JohnSmith.png

to

> ~/Photos/JohnSmith.png

but still no luck

[image]

tree:

[image]

And this is the result from what i'm getting:
[image]

As you can see I'm getting text and not the image as result.

Comment: can you see your image if you visit http://localhost:<port>/Photos/JohnSmith.png in the browser? - obviously replace <port> as applicable

Comment: Yes I can when i change the code in this it also works but this does not come from the database: <img src="~/Photos/JohnSmith.png" width="300" height="300" />

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Photo)
```

to this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(@Model.Photo)" />
```

in your Index.cshtml or Shop.cshtml

By your photos its look like there is a table and most be one of those file

Answer (score 0):

you can show image from this code

```
<img src="data:image/*;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Photo))">
```